# Input data to a database and read data from the database google sheets

Tags: javascript, c#

I am trying to make a Inventory Management system for a Sewing Business.

and i buy Treads clothes etc..

i want to maintain a inventory for those items in google sheets.

i want to create a dashboard for input data when i buy something.

maybe i create a submit form 1 to 10 rows and a submit button.

when i submit same item different quantities then i want automate the database to replace the old quantity to new quantity.

*Example:-*

**2 meter long red clothes
3 black treads**

and then i buy more 3 meters of red clothes and take out 1 black tread

and then the database must be updated as

**5 meter long red clothes
2 meter black treads**

like that..

i want to make the database, when i submit new items to the database i want to update the database. and when some items finishing in the stock i want to make a place for appear those items as next shopping list.

Comment: You may need to organize your data in row/column format.You will need to have a key to each row of the your sheet. The key is a unique value to be used when you read data or update data. I suggest you edit the sheet directly instead of this complex design. It will take you significant time and effort to implement in C#.

Comment: please if you can send me a youtube video URL for me to learn that thing to create a application what i want

Comment: You need some knowledge about Spreadsheets. But building an application is really a long way.